# Print result of a function

Tags: scala, printing, intellij-idea

How can I change this function in Scala to be able, when running it on IntelliJ IDEA, to see the result?

```
object poisson_sample_size extends App {

  def main(theta1: Double, theta2: Double): Double = {

    val theta1 = 0.0025
    val theta2 = 0.0030

    val num = 4
    val den = ((theta1 + theta2) / 2) - math.sqrt(theta1 * theta2)

    val x = num / den
    println(x: Double)
  }
}
```

I would like just to check the result is what I'm expecting it to be. I'm not sure it's error proof considering I just started learning Scala.

I've trying to attribute the result of `(num / den)` to a variable and then `print` the variable itself but it doesn't do what I was expecting.

Comment: Why don't you show the code where you are trying to print it

Comment: @m-z: I would just `println` it, considering it's just a sort of debugging step I want to run to make sure the function returns the right results.
@cmbaxter: I've edited the code to include the print statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your code to something like this:

```
object poisson_sample_size extends App {
  val t1 = 0.0025
  val t2 = 0.0030

  val result = calculate(t1, t2)
  println(result)

  def calculate(theta1: Double, theta2: Double): Double = {         
    val num = 4
    val den = ((theta1 + theta2) / 2) - math.sqrt(theta1 * theta2)

    num / den       
  }
}
```

By making your object extend `App`, you get a `main` method for free.  Then, using `main` is not a good idea for your custom calculation method as it creates confusion with a real `main` method, so I changed it to `calculate`.  Then, you need to make sure your `calculate` method is being called, which is probably the real reason why you don't see anything getting printed in your current example.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, to maintain the intended result for the function `main` you just need to insert `x` as the last statement in your function, which has an implicit `return` meaning in Scala.

```
object poisson_sample_size extends App {

  def main(theta1: Double, theta2: Double): Double = {
    val num = 4
    val den = ((theta1 + theta2) / 2) - math.sqrt(theta1 * theta2)

    val x = num / den
    println(x: Double)
    x // same as: return x
  }

  val theta1 = 0.0025
  val theta2 = 0.0030
  main(theta1, theta2)
}
```

In the way it is now, you should get a compile error message, as println has a `Unit` return type, but you declared `main` as having a `Double` return type.

Note that when you extend `App` you don't have to implement the `main` method. The actual body of the `object` is executed when the app is run. Try this modified version, please.

Comment: Thanks @Andre for your answer. I've changed `main` to return a `Unit`. Unfortunately this doesn't print on the console the value of `x`.

Comment: @Gianluca now I see what you're trying to do. Please, consider this new version of the answer. You don't have to implement the `main` method when you extend `App`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the chaining operation [`tap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap[U](f:A=%3EU):A) can be used as such:

```
import scala.util.chaining._

def f(): Int = calculate().tap(println)
```

to avoid such a construct:

```
def f(): Int = {
  val x: Int = calculate()
  println(x)
  x
}
```

---

The [`tap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap[U](f:A=%3EU):A) chaining operation applies a side effect (in this case `println`) on a value while returning the original value:

> def tap[U](f: (A) => U): A